# How to check whether a particular username or password is correct or the session is created after authorization

Tags: java

How can I check whether a particular username or password is correct or the session is created after getting authorized?

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        final String uid=jTextField1.getText();
        String pass = new String(jPasswordField1.getPassword());

        //server Config
        Properties prop=new Properties();
        prop.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.host","smtp.gmail.com");   
        prop.put("mail.smtp.port","587");

        //client Authentication
        Authenticator auth=new Authenticator()
        {
          protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
        {
          return new PasswordAuthentication(uid,pass);
        }
        };

        //Session Creation
        Session session= Session.getInstance(prop,auth);

    try{
        String to=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("To :");
        String sub=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Subject :");
        String data=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Compose :"); 

        //Message Creation
        Message msg=new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(uid));
  msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(to));
        msg.setSubject(sub);
        msg.setText(data);
        //sending msg
        Transport.send(msg);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"sent !");

        // TODO add your handling code here:
         } catch (MessagingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try
{
transport.connect(host, port, user, pwd);
}
 catch(AuthenticationFailedException e) {
   System.out.println("AuthenticationFailedException - for authentication failures");
   }
```

try this..... connect tries to make a connection with the server using given username and password.
it returns an exception if connection could not be established
put your invalid username/password code in catch block.